# Symfony 2 Routing Annotation with container parameter

Tags: symfony

I am  trying to "port" yml routing to annotations.
In yml I have route:

```
homepage_foo:
    pattern:  /foo
    defaults: { _controller: FooBundle:Homepage:foo }
    schemes:  [%httpProtocol%]
```

where %httpProtocol% is parameter from container.

With annotation, similar approach is not working:

```
/**
  * @Route("/foo", name="homepage_foo", schemes={%httpProtocol%})
  */
```

I am trying to use parameter %httpProtocol% with annotation. Is it possible with different syntax?

Comment: Have you [imported the annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation) for that controller (or for all)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, annotations as such works. I corrected question, it does not work with `schemes={%httpProtocol%}`

Comment: Try like did in "name-placeholders" adding: `schemes={httpProtocol}` and `requirements = { "httpProtocol" = "%httpProtocol%"`

Comment: No success with this:/

Comment: PS: In my previous comment there is a TYPO because I forgot to add the ending bracket in `requirements`.

Comment: I had probably other syntax issue. Thanks with help, solution is in answer.

Comment: I'm tired, I haven't seen that you used the brackets for `schemes` instead of "" :-)

Answer (score 4):

Works with:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo", name="homepage_foo", schemes="%httpProtocol%")
 */
```